# Understanding NAudio and converting buffer to floats

Tags: audio, processing, naudio

I create my capture passing in the samplerate(48000) and Channels(2)

```cpp
capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(device);
capture.WaveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(SampleRate, Channels);
// Hook up the DataAvailable event to process audio
capture.DataAvailable += Capture_DataAvailable;
```

then during the callback I want to convert the buffer to floats to process and this is my issue ... I am new to this stuff so online it shows you have to convert the bytes back to floats

```cpp
// Convert the bytes to floats for processing 
var samples = new float[e.BytesRecorded / 3]; 
for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 3) 
{ 
  // Convert the 24-bit sample to float 
  int sample = e.Buffer[i] | (e.Buffer[i + 1] << 8) | (e.Buffer[i + 2] << 16); 
  samples[i / 3] = sample / (float)0x7FFFFF; 
} 
// Split the samples into left and right channels 
float[] leftChannel = new float[samples.Length / 2]; 
float[] rightChannel = new float[samples.Length / 2]; 
for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i += 2) 
{ 
  leftChannel[i / 2] = samples[i]; 
  rightChannel[i / 2] = samples[i + 1]; 
}
```

My question here is, when I am only playing audio which is only in left ear, I would expect all the left channels to have values and then the right channel to be all 0's?
but currently both arrays are full of non 0 data

What am I missing here or am I completely off tracks?

See above for my code used ... but I understand the device is 24 bit, 2 channels and 48000 Hz as shown in sound windows properties.

I am guessing either my logic/understanding of what is needed is wrong or it's valid for the right channel to get float values back even though the audio playing while testing is a audio clip of music playing in just the left ear.

Answer (score 0):

`WasapiLoopbackCapture` will always return IEEE float, not 24 bit audio, so the byte array already contains floats. The `WaveBuffer` class can be used as an efficient way to access the contents of a `byte[]` as though it were a `float[]`. Create a new `WaveBuffer` bound to the byte array and access it through the `FloatBuffer` property